# Sync music folder with android

Tags: android, sync, music

So I looked in the forum for solution for my problem but I didn't find it.
I have android phone and my music is at external hard drive. 
What I want is to be able to sync my music from the external hard drive to the android phone.

I already tried Clementine and the problem was it's always copy the full music and doesn't sync the music (if I already had the song in the phone it copy it again).

The next thing I tried was Banshee. same results.

I know Rhythmbox has sync option but it's asking me to copy the whole music to the computer and I don't want to.

So I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing files is the same as copying them to an external device (such as your phone). Your problem is that all the media players and syncing software (Rhythmbox, Banshee, Clementine) can only copy your files to your phone (either you have them there or not) because they are on the external hard drive. I think that the software is not compatible with syncing files from one external device to another. That's why it copies your files only. Rhythmbox displays the error more detailed since it's (kind of) more advanced and it needs the files on your computer to perform the syncing process.

If you encounter any issues, feel free to inform me.

Comment: I used to sync with windows media player, and now I have some music on the phone. but for example Clementine tries to copy the whole music again, so it's double the memory size of the music (It's doesn't recognize the music I already have there)

Comment: @ShakedE Maybe there is a bug. I'm not really sure...  If you have dual-boot (Windows & Ubuntu), boot to Windows, connect the external hard drive and sync your music from there. I think that is the best option (since file syncing worked with Windows Media Player).

Comment: @Bajru Thx for the help. That what I am doing today. Thought there may be a solution. Perhaps it's because I sync it first through windows Ubuntu doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @ShakedE Maybe... I'm really sure it's this (Ubuntu sync does not recognize Windows Media sync)